# Unable start Android Studio 1.3.2 with android M

Tags: android, android-studio

I've updated android sdk to sdk platform 23 (android M) and now I cannot start android studio. It's my error, please help me:

Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.createWelcomeScreen(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:147)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.createScreen(WelcomeFrame.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.<init>(WelcomeFrame.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:173)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too. This fixed my problem -
 1) Update Android Studio to the latest version along with Android SDK WITH platform tools and build tools.
 2) If this doesn't work, do a CLEAN install of Android Studio along with Android SDK. 
 This should solve your problem. If this solves your problem, "accept" this answer please.

Comment: please tell me how to clean install Android Studio. You mean unistall and reinstall it

Comment: Yeah. First delete Android Studio then install it again. Clean installing SDK is not necessary. **PS -** Don't update Studio to a unstable version. Only update it to a stable version or it might crash.

Answer (score 0):

The quick method that worked for me was removing the Android Studio config folder `~/.AndroidStudio`. So, the next time the IDE loaded, it looked like a fresh install and I pointed to same SDK. No downloads required.